# Deserialization of properties won't work, but works in TestProject and Generic-Lists

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, properties, deserialization

i have a rally weird problem with the deserialization of my ApplicationSettings-Class.
The class looks like following:

```
[Serializable]
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    public string SelectedGeneralSetting { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCheckSetting { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDataBaseSetting { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCompareSetting { get; set; }

    public List<GeneralSetting> GeneralSettings = new List<GeneralSetting>();
    public List<CheckSetting> CheckSettings = new List<CheckSetting>();
    public List<DataBaseSetting> DataBaseSettings = new List<DataBaseSetting>();
    public List<CompareSetting> CompareSettings = new List<CompareSetting>();

    public ApplicationSettings()
    {

    }
}
```

The serialization of this class just works fine, but deserialization won't work, the public properties SelectedGeneralSetting, SelectedCheckSetting, SelectedDataBaseSetting  and SelectedCompareSetting are null. I'm deserializing using this method:

```
private void deserialize()
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
    FileStream file = new FileStream(ApplicationSettingsPath + @"\settings.xml", FileMode.Open);
    ApplicationSettings = (serializer.Deserialize(file) as ApplicationSettings);
    file.Close();
 }
```

There are two strange things, the Lists contain also a lot of properties and they are deserilized correctly. I created a test-project, containing a public member and property and a generic list, all were successfully deserialized. I really have no Idea why it shouldn't work in my "main-project". Does anyone have an advice? How can the deserialization behave so weird?
Greetings!

Comment: SelectedGeneralSetting is string and GeneralSettings is list of GeneralSetting. It is not clear what is expected in SelectedGeneralSetting. Post the xml you are trying to deserialize from

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ApplicationSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SelectedGeneralSetting>Default</SelectedGeneralSetting>
  <SelectedCheckSetting>Default</SelectedCheckSetting>[br]
  <SelectedDataBaseSetting>Default</SelectedDataBaseSetting>
  <SelectedCompareSetting>Default</SelectedCompareSetting>
  <GeneralSettings>
    <GeneralSetting Name="Default">
      ...Properties which are deserialized just fine...
    </GeneralSetting>
  </GeneralSettings>

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(
                    @"<?xml version=""1.0""?> <ApplicationSettings>
 <SelectedGeneralSetting>Default</SelectedGeneralSetting>
    <GeneralSettings>
    <GeneralSetting><Name>DDD</Name></GeneralSetting>
    </GeneralSettings></ApplicationSettings>"));
                var result = (serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ApplicationSettings);
            }

            [Serializable]
            public class ApplicationSettings
            {
                public string SelectedGeneralSetting { get; set; }
                public List<GeneralSetting> GeneralSettings = new List<GeneralSetting>();
            }

            public class GeneralSetting
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
            }
```

Check [BR] text in your sample text

Comment: Thank you hungryMind for your effort and answer. The strange thing is, as mentioned above, the deserialization works just fine with the same deserialization code in the test-project. And i don't see any differences between the algorithms or declarations in these two projects but in one case it deserializes the properties, in the other project it doesn't.

Comment: Check your .net version and serializer settings as well as check your source file. Weird but I don't see any other issue.

Comment: I've changed the .NET Version on both projects to 4.0 and unfortunately the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the variable name in `deserialize()`?

It should be:

```cs
ApplicationSettings settings = (serializer.Deserialize(file) as ApplicationSettings);
```

Comment: No, actually ApplicationSettings is the instance of ApplicationSettings ;) Its really really weird... I will take a look if it's because of the directory i'm reading the serialized settings from. But why should it deserialize the properties in one case, but not in the other? :(

Comment: Try checking your xml file path whether it is valid.

Comment: It is valid, because otherwise it wouldn't deserialize the instance "GeneralSettings" or would even crash. Once again, two projects, same deserialization-code, one deserializes public properties and members, the other just public members. And the project, in which only members are deserialized, the properties of the generic lists are deserialized withouth a problem. :-/